# Removing quotes from a variable passed as an argument

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a variable called `color`, which is an HSL value, and I'm trying to pass it into a function that typically takes a series of numbers as the HSL values.

**This doesn't work:**

```
var color = "210,50,50";
stroke(color);
```

**This does work:**

```
stroke(210,50,50);
```

I've tried a bunch of string replacement functions like:

```
stroke(color.replace(/\"/g,""))
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is a single value. The `stroke()` function is expecting 3 individual values.

You can use the `split()` function to split the string into the individual numbers. Something like this:

```
var color = "210,50,50";
var colorArray = split(color, ",");
var red = colorArray[0];
var green = colorArray[1];
var blue = colorArray[2];
stroke(red, green, blue);
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/split).

Actually, robstarbuck pointed out that the `stroke()` function takes an array as an argument as well, so you could even do:

```
var color = "210,50,50";
var colorArray = split(color, ",");
stroke(colorArray);
```

Comment: @Modermo Haha nah you're not an idiot. It happens to all of us.

Comment: On second viewing of your code, shouldn't the last line be `stroke(colorArray)`, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Modermo Doh, my bad. Just fixed it. See, told you it happens to all of us!

Comment: Also, just realised that if you actually wrap the color value in it's respective color mode i.e. `var color = 'hsba(160, 100%, 50%, 0.5)' `, it works without needing to `split` the string

Comment: Please note that the OP said that `color` holds HSL values, not RGB, so I guess you should rename your variables.

Answer (score 3):

It's best to define your values as an array and pass that to [stroke](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/stroke) as your one argument (see [docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/stroke)).

```js
var color = [210, 50, 50]
stroke(color)
```

[See Example](https://jsfiddle.net/robstarbuck/w07x9rxt/)

Comment: Why is this best?

Comment: @KevinWorkman, if not, why did you use it on your own answer (without mentioning @robstarbuck)?

Comment: @karliwson uhhh, what? I'm not saying it's not an option. I'm simply asking why it's the best option.

Comment: I suppose I meant for reusability within p5.js as other functions take `values` as their argument eg: [fill](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/fill) though I admit I don't know @modermo's use case.

Comment: @KevinWorkman It's just polite to mention one's name when his suggestion was useful to your own answer.

Comment: @karliwson uhhh, I already did that? Thanks for the downvote though. :p